# Strict Standards: Declaration of description_walker::start_el() and warning

Tags: theme-twenty-fourteen

I am getting problem like following in my website. i am just beginner of wordpress. so kindly help to fixed it.

> Strict Standards: Declaration of My_Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl() should be compatible with Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array) in /home/ramendraraj/public_html/wp-content/themes/ignitedtheme/functions.php on line 528
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ramendraraj/public_html/wp-content/themes/ignitedtheme/functions.php:527) in /home/ramendraraj/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1167

Editing:
/home/ramendraraj/public_html/wp-content/themes/ignitedtheme/functions.php
 Encoding:    Re-open Use Code Editor     Close  Save Changes

```
<?php
/**
 * Twenty Fourteen functions and definitions
 *
 * Set up the theme and provides some helper functions, which are used in the
 * theme as custom template tags. Others are attached to action and filter
 * hooks in WordPress to change core functionality.
 *
 * When using a child theme you can override certain functions (those wrapped
 * in a function_exists() call) by defining them first in your child theme's
 * functions.php file. The child theme's functions.php file is included before
 * the parent theme's file, so the child theme functions would be used.
 *
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
 *
 * Functions that are not pluggable (not wrapped in function_exists()) are
 * instead attached to a filter or action hook.
 *
 * For more information on hooks, actions, and filters,
 * @link https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */

/**
 * Set up the content width value based on the theme's design.
 *
 * @see twentyfourteen_content_width()
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
if ( ! isset( $content_width ) ) {
    $content_width = 474;
}

/**
 * Twenty Fourteen only works in WordPress 3.6 or later.
 */
if ( version_compare( $GLOBALS['wp_version'], '3.6', '<' ) ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/back-compat.php';
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_setup' ) ) :
/**
 * Twenty Fourteen setup.
 *
 * Set up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress features.
 *
 * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
 * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, such
 * as indicating support post thumbnails.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_setup() {

    /*
     * Make Twenty Fourteen available for translation.
     *
     * Translations can be added to the /languages/ directory.
     * If you're building a theme based on Twenty Fourteen, use a find and
     * replace to change 'twentyfourteen' to the name of your theme in all
     * template files.
     */
    load_theme_textdomain( 'twentyfourteen', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // This theme styles the visual editor to resemble the theme style.
    add_editor_style( array( 'css/editor-style.css', twentyfourteen_font_url(), 'genericons/genericons.css' ) );

    // Add RSS feed links to <head> for posts and comments.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // Enable support for Post Thumbnails, and declare two sizes.
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 672, 372, true );
    add_image_size( 'twentyfourteen-full-width', 1038, 576, true );

    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in two locations.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'primary'   => __( 'Top primary menu', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'secondary' => __( 'Secondary menu in left sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form', 'comment-form', 'comment-list', 'gallery', 'caption'
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Formats.
     * See https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats
     */
    add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array(
        'aside', 'image', 'video', 'audio', 'quote', 'link', 'gallery',
    ) );

    // This theme allows users to set a custom background.
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background', apply_filters( 'twentyfourteen_custom_background_args', array(
        'default-color' => 'f5f5f5',
    ) ) );

    // Add support for featured content.
    add_theme_support( 'featured-content', array(
        'featured_content_filter' => 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts',
        'max_posts' => 6,
    ) );

    // This theme uses its own gallery styles.
    add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', '__return_false' );
}
endif; // twentyfourteen_setup
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'twentyfourteen_setup' );

/**
 * Adjust content_width value for image attachment template.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_content_width() {
    if ( is_attachment() && wp_attachment_is_image() ) {
        $GLOBALS['content_width'] = 810;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'twentyfourteen_content_width' );

/**
 * Getter function for Featured Content Plugin.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
 * @return array An array of WP_Post objects.
 */
function twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts() {
    /**
     * Filter the featured posts to return in Twenty Fourteen.
     *
     * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
     *
     * @param array|bool $posts Array of featured posts, otherwise false.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts', array() );
}

/**
 * A helper conditional function that returns a boolean value.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
 * @return bool Whether there are featured posts.
 */
function twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts() {
    return ! is_paged() && (bool) twentyfourteen_get_featured_posts();
}

/**
 * Register three Twenty Fourteen widget areas.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_widgets_init() {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/widgets.php';
    register_widget( 'Twenty_Fourteen_Ephemera_Widget' );

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Primary Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Main sidebar that appears on the left.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Content Sidebar', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
        'description'   => __( 'Additional sidebar that appears on the right.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
                 'before_title'  => '<div class="title">',
        'after_title'   => '</div>',
    ) );
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Footer Widget Area', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-3',
        'description'   => __( 'Appears in the footer section of the site.', 'twentyfourteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h1 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h1>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'twentyfourteen_widgets_init' );

/**
 * Register Lato Google font for Twenty Fourteen.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
 * @return string
 */
function twentyfourteen_font_url() {
    $font_url = '';
    /*
     * Translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported
     * by Lato, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language.
     */
    if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Lato font: on or off', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) {
        $query_args = array(
            'family' => urlencode( 'Lato:300,400,700,900,300italic,400italic,700italic' ),
            'subset' => urlencode( 'latin,latin-ext' ),
        );
        $font_url = add_query_arg( $query_args, '//fonts.googleapis.com/css' );
    }

    return $font_url;
}

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles for the front end.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_scripts() {
    // Add Lato font, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfourteen-lato', twentyfourteen_font_url(), array(), null );

    // Add Genericons font, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'genericons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/genericons/genericons.css', array(), '3.0.3' );

    // Load our main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfourteen-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // Load the Internet Explorer specific stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfourteen-ie', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ie.css', array( 'twentyfourteen-style' ), '20131205' );
    wp_style_add_data( 'twentyfourteen-ie', 'conditional', 'lt IE 9' );

    if ( is_singular() && comments_open() && get_option( 'thread_comments' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );
    }

    if ( is_singular() && wp_attachment_is_image() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-keyboard-image-navigation', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/keyboard-image-navigation.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20130402' );
    }

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-masonry' );
    }

    if ( is_front_page() && 'slider' == get_theme_mod( 'featured_content_layout' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20131205', true );
        wp_localize_script( 'twentyfourteen-slider', 'featuredSliderDefaults', array(
            'prevText' => __( 'Previous', 'twentyfourteen' ),
            'nextText' => __( 'Next', 'twentyfourteen' )
        ) );
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'twentyfourteen-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/functions.js', array( 'jquery' ), '20150315', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentyfourteen_scripts' );

/**
 * Enqueue Google fonts style to admin screen for custom header display.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_admin_fonts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'twentyfourteen-lato', twentyfourteen_font_url(), array(), null );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-appearance_page_custom-header', 'twentyfourteen_admin_fonts' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_the_attached_image' ) ) :
/**
 * Print the attached image with a link to the next attached image.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_the_attached_image() {
    $post                = get_post();
    /**
     * Filter the default Twenty Fourteen attachment size.
     *
     * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
     *
     * @param array $dimensions {
     *     An array of height and width dimensions.
     *
     *     @type int $height Height of the image in pixels. Default 810.
     *     @type int $width  Width of the image in pixels. Default 810.
     * }
     */
    $attachment_size     = apply_filters( 'twentyfourteen_attachment_size', array( 810, 810 ) );
    $next_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url();

    /*
     * Grab the IDs of all the image attachments in a gallery so we can get the URL
     * of the next adjacent image in a gallery, or the first image (if we're
     * looking at the last image in a gallery), or, in a gallery of one, just the
     * link to that image file.
     */
    $attachment_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
        'fields'         => 'ids',
        'numberposts'    => -1,
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'order'          => 'ASC',
        'orderby'        => 'menu_order ID',
    ) );

    // If there is more than 1 attachment in a gallery...
    if ( count( $attachment_ids ) > 1 ) {
        foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
            if ( $attachment_id == $post->ID ) {
                $next_id = current( $attachment_ids );
                break;
            }
        }

        // get the URL of the next image attachment...
        if ( $next_id ) {
            $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $next_id );
        }

        // or get the URL of the first image attachment.
        else {
            $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( reset( $attachment_ids ) );
        }
    }

    printf( '<a href="%1$s" rel="attachment">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( $next_attachment_url ),
        wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $attachment_size )
    );
}
endif;

if ( ! function_exists( 'twentyfourteen_list_authors' ) ) :
/**
 * Print a list of all site contributors who published at least one post.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
function twentyfourteen_list_authors() {
    $contributor_ids = get_users( array(
        'fields'  => 'ID',
        'orderby' => 'post_count',
        'order'   => 'DESC',
        'who'     => 'authors',
    ) );

    foreach ( $contributor_ids as $contributor_id ) :
        $post_count = count_user_posts( $contributor_id );

        // Move on if user has not published a post (yet).
        if ( ! $post_count ) {
            continue;
        }
    ?>

    <div class="contributor">
        <div class="contributor-info">
            <div class="contributor-avatar"><?php echo get_avatar( $contributor_id, 132 ); ?></div>
            <div class="contributor-summary">
                <h2 class="contributor-name"><?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $contributor_id ); ?></h2>
                <p class="contributor-bio">
                    <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'description', $contributor_id ); ?>
                </p>
                <a class="button contributor-posts-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( $contributor_id ) ); ?>">
                    <?php printf( _n( '%d Article', '%d Articles', $post_count, 'twentyfourteen' ), $post_count ); ?>
                </a>
            </div><!-- .contributor-summary -->
        </div><!-- .contributor-info -->
    </div><!-- .contributor -->

    <?php
    endforeach;
}
endif;

/**
 * Extend the default WordPress body classes.
 *
 * Adds body classes to denote:
 * 1. Single or multiple authors.
 * 2. Presence of header image except in Multisite signup and activate pages.
 * 3. Index views.
 * 4. Full-width content layout.
 * 5. Presence of footer widgets.
 * 6. Single views.
 * 7. Featured content layout.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $classes A list of existing body class values.
 * @return array The filtered body class list.
 */
function twentyfourteen_body_classes( $classes ) {
    if ( is_multi_author() ) {
        $classes[] = 'group-blog';
    }

    if ( get_header_image() ) {
        $classes[] = 'header-image';
    } elseif ( ! in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-activate.php', 'wp-signup.php' ) ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'masthead-fixed';
    }

    if ( is_archive() || is_search() || is_home() ) {
        $classes[] = 'list-view';
    }

    if ( ( ! is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) )
        || is_page_template( 'page-templates/full-width.php' )
        || is_page_template( 'page-templates/contributors.php' )
        || is_attachment() ) {
        $classes[] = 'full-width';
    }

    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'footer-widgets';
    }

    if ( is_singular() && ! is_front_page() ) {
        $classes[] = 'singular';
    }

    if ( is_front_page() && 'slider' == get_theme_mod( 'featured_content_layout' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'slider';
    } elseif ( is_front_page() ) {
        $classes[] = 'grid';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'twentyfourteen_body_classes' );

/**
 * Extend the default WordPress post classes.
 *
 * Adds a post class to denote:
 * Non-password protected page with a post thumbnail.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
 * @param array $classes A list of existing post class values.
 * @return array The filtered post class list.
 */
function twentyfourteen_post_classes( $classes ) {
    if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() && has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        $classes[] = 'has-post-thumbnail';
    }

    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'post_class', 'twentyfourteen_post_classes' );

/**
 * Create a nicely formatted and more specific title element text for output
 * in head of document, based on current view.
 *
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 *
 * @global int $paged WordPress archive pagination page count.
 * @global int $page  WordPress paginated post page count.
 *
 * @param string $title Default title text for current view.
 * @param string $sep Optional separator.
 * @return string The filtered title.
 */
function twentyfourteen_wp_title( $title, $sep ) {
    global $paged, $page;

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        return $title;
    }

    // Add the site name.
    $title .= get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' );

    // Add the site description for the home/front page.
    $site_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
    if ( $site_description && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) {
        $title = "$title $sep $site_description";
    }

    // Add a page number if necessary.
    if ( ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) {
        $title = "$title $sep " . sprintf( __( 'Page %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), max( $paged, $page ) );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'wp_title', 'twentyfourteen_wp_title', 10, 2 );

// Implement Custom Header features.
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/custom-header.php';

// Custom template tags for this theme.
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/template-tags.php';

// Add Customizer functionality.
require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';

/*
 * Add Featured Content functionality.
 *
 * To overwrite in a plugin, define your own Featured_Content class on or
 * before the 'setup_theme' hook.
 */
if ( ! class_exists( 'Featured_Content' ) && 'plugins.php' !== $GLOBALS['pagenow'] ) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/featured-content.php';
}

//for sub page add subul class and add in header.php 'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu() ) );
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
  function start_lvl(&$output, $depth) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
  }

}
```

Comment: This is way too much code for one question, especially unformatted. Please narrow down your questions code to what the issue is referring to. Then read over [Formatting](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and edit your question ( using the Edit button above ).

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you're asking for error with `Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el()` or `Walker_Nav_Menu::start_lvl()`. But you must specify all arguments as default in the `Walker_Nav_Menu` class in your derived classes. E.g:

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
  /**
   * Starts the list before the elements are added.
   *
   * @see Walker::start_lvl()
   */
  public function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array())
  {
    // your code...
  }

  /**
   * Start the element output.
   *
   * @see Walker::start_el()
   */
  public function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0)
  {
    // your code...
  }
}
```